# addToBackStack doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

all! 
I have 2  fragments. First one appears at start, second  one adds  with  button  "Add", using the same container.I am trying to add fragment to the back stack with method `addToBackStack`, but when I click "back-button" my app hides instead of showing me the first fragment. What is wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirstFragment fragment1;
SecondFragment fragment2;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
FragmentManager fm;
Button add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
    fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new FirstFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: use fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Some tag Instead of null");

Comment: Have you overridden onBackPressed() callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addToBackStack() on fragment transaction is not enough, we have to handle the popping up of the back stack upon **Back button pressed** by ourselves.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
 }
```

Comment: you don't need to handle backstack if you have properly added to back stack while while calling commit